# 5 seconds between comment edit is broken

Tags: bug, comments

4 minutes after posting a comment I quickly fixed a sentence. Too quickly, as I made a typo. Trying to fix the typo as fast as possible, I got "You may only edit a comment every 5 seconds". So I waited 3 more seconds and tried again. Same message. I waited *another* 3 seconds, and again I got the same message. This time I waited 6 seconds, and still I got the same message!!. I refreshed the page, and the 5 minutes already elapsed and now the typo is burned into history.

Either:

- Bug: The 5 second counter is reset on every press of "Save Edits", and/or
- Bug: It gives the wrong "5 seconds" message because the 5 minutes were elapsed.

Comment: I'm on a broadband connection that never has notable ping or jitter.

Comment: Do you have any browser plugins or userscripts enabled?  Try disabling them temporarily next time to see if they are interfering.  According to my tests here in a separate unprivileged test account, this 'still works' as normal.